# React Native Expo error: "'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" while setting up the project

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, expo

While setting up the environment for an authentication app using React native and expo

These are the code I have ran:

```
expo init firebaseauth
npm install @react-navigation/native
expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
npm install @react-navigation/native-stack
```

But while running `expo install firebase`  in VS code terminal its is returning:

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Action taken after that:

1. Installed the latest version of Node and NPM.
2. Set up the environment variable to `C:\Program Files\nodejs`
3. Restarted my system

Still its returning the same error in VS code terminal while running `expo install firebase`

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting the system, Node was recognized by my vs code terminal.

After that Yarn was throwing the same error.

I had to update Node, npm, yarn, and expo from Windows PowerShell as admin. Otherwise, none of it works if you don't update all of them from as admin.